# Solve the circuit using Thevenin

Tags: thevenin

i need your help to solve this simple circuit using Thevenin, i used Ohm to solve but using thevenin the values was diferent, so i need your help, the question is the voltage at R4 and the current at R6, thanks a lot.

[image: Thevenin Circuit]

I do this:
[image]

Comment: Show your work and we might point out what you messed up. Without knowing what you did, though, we can hardly figure out what you did wrong.

Comment: What you showed is correct so far. That should give you the correct result for voltage across R4. For current through R6, if required to use thevenin, you'll have to go back and find a new equivalent source connected at the terminals of R6.

Comment: @ThePhoton Except that it looks like the OP computed \$R_{TH}=\left(40\:\Omega\vert\vert 120\:\Omega\right)+80\:\Omega=320\:\Omega\$ instead of \$\left(40\:\Omega\vert\vert 120\:\Omega\right)+80\:\Omega=110\:\Omega\$ for that step.

Comment: Can you do \$I_6\$?

Comment: @jonk yeah my mistake, to find the Voltage at R6 now i get the resistence 110 and voltage 7.5v can i use Ohms law?

Answer (score 1):

Douglas, the question regarding the voltage across \$R_4\$ should be easily solved using your own approach. *CASE 1* below shows what I believe you arrived at, though as I said I think you miscalculated the resulting \$R_{TH}\$. I've shown what I think the equivalent should be on the right side of it. You should be able to easily apply Ohm's law now to work out the voltage across \$R_4\$. Compute the total current and apply that to \$R_4\$.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flvuNF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've also shown above your \$R_6\$ question. I hope I followed the approach you were being taught by breaking the connections around that resistor. From there, it's very simple to work out the value of \$R_{\vert\vert}\$, replacing four resistors with just one. The rest should be again quite easy to do, as you have a simple circuit and it should be easy to calculate the total current in it. That will also, of course, be the current in \$R_6\$.

Comment: R4 perfect , i forgotten put back R4....My mistake, but R6 i still dont understand, what you do OK, no problem, but after that i use the voltage of R3 to find the current?

Comment: @DouglasNickson Just sum up the series resistance of all three resistors and use that to compute the loop current. Since all of the loop current must also flow through \$R_6\$, you have your answer for the current in \$R_6\$.

Comment: The sum of 60 + 20 + 20? This is not ohms law? It's not necessary find RTH and VTH?

Comment: @DouglasNickson No, it's not necessary. But if you did, \$R_{TH}\$ would just be the sum of \$R_1\$ and \$R_{\vert\vert}\$.

Comment: hum, but in this part of the circuit when i open the terminals at R6 the voltage will not be 0? So How can i find VTh?

Comment: @DouglasNickson It's not necessary to find \$R_{TH}\$ in order to find the current in \$R_6\$. Can you get from the lower left circuit to the lower right circuit on your own? Then, assuming that \$R_6\$ is hooked back up into the lower right circuit, are you able to find the current in the resulting simplified circuit? Or not?

Comment: yeah, i know How find the current , and i understand what you said, but i still dont understand How can i find the current using Thevenin..

Comment: @DouglasNickson I think I'm confused about your confusion then. It's so simple at this point. Just create \$R_{TH}=R_1+R_{\vert\vert}=20\:\Omega+60\:\Omega=80\:\Omega\$ in the lower right side circuit.

Comment: yeah it's very simple, my problem is understand using Thevenin, because in this case , RTH OK, but How can i find VTh? Because with the circuit open the Voltage at the left was 0, or not? I try to find the RTH, VTH, and after that mount the circuit with VTH and RTH, and finally find the current, i dont know if i think wrong...

Answer (score -1):

Simple.... Your Rth is wrong... 
Rth =  ((20+20)//120) +40+40
Then solving this we get it as 
=>(40//120)+80
=>(40*120/(120+40)) + 80
=> (4800/160)+80
=> 30+80
=> 110
Rth=110 ohms...... Now Vth as u already calculated is 7.5 
Voltage across r4 is Vth * r4/(r4+Rth) 
7.5*40/(40+110).........=> 7.5*4/15
===2 v

Comment: It's possible use Ohms law to find the voltage at R4? Because using Ohms law the voltage that a get was 2.72v

Comment: Show how you solved it using ohm's law.... May be there is  some mistake

Comment: yeah, i did some things wrong, but now using Ohms is correct, i find 2v, but, can't find the current at R6 using Thevenin, can you help me please?